# How do I select the concatination of '$' and the value of a table column?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to concatenate a dollar sign with the value of a table column in a SELECT query. Could someone tell me why my SQL is producing an error? (I would include more info, but this is really a simple problem)

SQL Code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Item_Types (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255), avgcost DECIMAL(9, 2));
SELECT id AS 'item no.' name As 'Item' !Problem!CONCAT('$', Item_Types.avgcost) AS
'Average Cost ($)' FROM Item_Types;`
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot some commas... Try this :

```
SELECT id AS 'item no.', name As 'Item', CONCAT('$', Item_Types.avgcost) AS
'Average Cost ($)' FROM Item_Types;
```